# parent and child directive communication issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have two directives - a parent and a child 
in the parent directive controller i have this particular code

```
$scope.someRandomFunction = function(){
        someService.getSomeRandomData().then(function (data) {
          $scope.dataForSomething = [];
          data.forEach(function(value) {
            var obj= {};
            obj.id = value.id
            obj.name = value.name;
            obj.moreData = [];
            $scope.dataForSomething.push(obj);
          });

          getData();
        });
      };

function getData(){
        sharedService.getSomething(opts).then(function (data) {
          //i'm putting some data in obj.moreData from the data that i get here 
        });
      }
```

In my view i have

```
<parent-directive>
    <div ng-repeat="val in dataForSomething">
        <track val="val"></track>
    </div>
</parent-directive>
```

The issue is before i get data from getData() - child directive executes due to which val.moreData comes out undefined as data has not yet come from the call made.

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the data after the getData() promise has finished. Rather then access data from the scope. Try to chain promises by returning new values for the next call to `then`.

For example, `getData` and return `innerData`.

```
$scope.someRandomFunction = function(){
        someService.getSomeRandomData().then(function (outerData) {
          $scope.dataForSomething = [];
          getData(outerData).then(function(innerData){
             outerData.forEach(function(value) {
                 var obj= {};
                 obj.id = value.id
                 obj.name = value.name;
                 obj.moreData = [];
                 // array is updated after everything is ready.
                 $scope.dataForSomething.push(obj);
             });
          });
        });
      };

function getData(){
        return sharedService.getSomething(opts).then(function (data) {
             // do stuff with data, and then return it
             return data; // <-- turns into innerData var
        });
      }


<parent-directive>
    <div ng-repeat="val in dataForSomething">
        <track val="val"></track>
    </div>
</parent-directive>
```